# Chain with a barrier in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to achieve the layout below using a ConstraintLayout with no nesting.

[image]

The layout requires a barrier since it's not guaranteed which textview will be taller. It also requires a chain since everything needs to be centered. The issue is that I can't find a way to make chain work with barriers.

Here's what I have so far which will layout correctly but will not center:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topLeftText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        tools:text="Test test test test test test test test test test"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/topRightText"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topRightText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        tools:text="Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/topLeftText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="topLeftText,topRightText"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        tools:text="Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If anyone knows how to achieve this, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to constrain top of top left text view to top of top right text view. Then constrain top right and bottom text views to barrier

Comment: Did you solve your problem, if yes how? I am currently facing a similar problem, and the only solution that i can think of otherwise, is using a nested layout. Which kinda contradicts the use of a ConstraintLayout, keeping the hierarchy flat.

Comment: have you found a workaround?

Comment: Is the problem you are facing that you cannot centre everything vertically? If this is the case maybe you can try using a horizontal guideline instead of a barrier?

Comment: @TreyWurm I used a nested layout. Since this question still has no answers I think it's probably this is impossible to achieve without changes to ConstraintLayout.

Comment: It just blows me away that there's no answer from google devs for this query till date.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old but i think to do that without nesting, you have to change top component to something like this.

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:layout_gravity="center"

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Comment: The question is about centering TextViews inside ConstraintLayout. Your answer is about centering the ConstraintLayout inside it's parent. That is nesting, because you have to add such parent.

Comment: @Agent_L There's no nesting in this answer. It's showing that the root/parent (ConstraintLayout in this case) can be wrapped and centered as a whole. There's no extra ViewGroup defined. Although the solution doesn't answer whether barrier chaining can be done it does show that the content can be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a guideline instead of a barrier. Let me know if this works for you:

Since you are not using androidx, make sure to replace `androidx.constraintlayout.widget` with `android.support.constraint`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topLeftText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/topRightText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Test test test test test test test test test test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topRightText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/topLeftText"
        tools:text="Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it will look like

[image]

Comment: This solution does not center the content as a unit. Imagine a situation where the text views at the top are a lot shorter than the text view at the bottom or vise versa.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean. Nesting the 2 upper views is an alternative, but I know that it doesn't answer your question.